# Add a custom function to a M2M descendant

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model like this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    date_v_fin = models.DateTimeField(
        default=None,
        null=True,
        editable=True,
        verbose_name=_(u"V. end"),
        blank=True
    )

class Personne(BaseModel):
    types_permis = models.ManyToManyField(
        TagTraduit, blank=True, default=None, symmetrical=False,
        through='PersonneTypepermis',
        related_name='personne_typepermis')
```

What I've tried to do is to override `ManyToManyField` to add a custom function like this:

```
class ManyToManyStillValid(models.ManyToManyField):

    def all_valid(self):
        print "i came here"
        return self.all().filter(date_v_fin__null=True)
```

This way I thought I could be able to use it like this in my template:

```
{% for item in personne.types_permis.all_valid %}
    <br/>{{ item }}
{% empty %}
    <br/>{% trans 'No driving licence provided' %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesnt work, the function `all_valid()` is never called. What am I missing?

---

Update
After reading the answers I've tried to use a custom manager like this:

First create my custom manager:

```
class ObjectsStillValidManager(models.Manager):
    def still_valid(self):
        return super(ObjectsStillValidManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            date_v_fin__exact=None)
```

Then add `objects = ObjectsStillValidManager()` to my manytomany *intermediate* model:

```
class PersonneTypepermis(BaseModel):
    personne = models.ForeignKey(Personne, verbose_name=_(u'Person'))
    type_permis = models.ForeignKey(TagTraduit, verbose_name=_(u'Licence'))
    objects = ObjectsStillValidManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return _(u'{} / {}').format(self.personne, self.type_permis)
```

But it seems I cant call `still_valid` like this:

```
{% for item in personne.types_permis.still_valid %}
{% endfor %}
```

because `still_valid` is never called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way to do it.

You may want to have a look at [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've edited my question, I didnt manage to use custom manager.

Comment: Don't use super in still_valid method, just return self.get_queryset().filter(date_v_fin__isnull=True)

Comment: I check your answer as valid and if you dont mind may I add my working solution to your answer?

Comment: Sure, it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong approach to define function on model, use [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) for this.

Now problem is you can't call a function from template(html page) call that function on view and render data in [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#example).

With context data on view
 
`_list_of_data = personne.types_permis2.all_valid()
 {'_list_of_data':_list_of_data}`

Now add this in context on render function 

Then iterate over it on html

`{% for item in _list_of_data %}
 ....
 ....
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've edited my question, I didnt manage to use custom manager.